# wxAutomationObject for Excel File Manipulation in C++

Tags: wxwidgets

I'm relatively new to wxWidget and am currently working on a C++ program that requires the use of wxAutomationObject. Specifically, I need to open an Excel file and write string into multiple cell. Does anyone have an example or guidance on how to effectively utilize this class for such task?
Thank you in advance for any assistance provided.

I'm trying to achieve this but I'm not getting solution please let me know how I can do this.

Comment: check wx forum. There are library to do just that.

Comment: There was a relatively recent request to do just that and the thread have a solution.

Comment: No this is not related to this topic.

Comment: I was referring to the PB post about wxAutoExcel... But I see that you already did post there and he mentioned that library there as well...

Comment: As Igor posted, I have already answered you on the wxForum, providing full compilable code showing how to open an Excel file and write to it, using wxAutomationObject: https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=51205

No idea why you ignored my answers and posted here instead.

Comment: ohh I didn't seen before that answer that's why I wasted here for getting solution.